# helper methods not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I've got a `CopiesHelper` module with a method `cc`.

In my `ApplicationController`, I have

```
helper :all 
helper_method :cc #just tried putting this in recently
```

If in another one of my Controllers, I try using the `cc` method, I get

```
undefined method 'cc' for #<OtherController:0xblublublublub>
```

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your `CopiesHelper` in one of your controller, simply do :

in **{app_dir}/app/controllers/your_controller.rb**

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
    include CopiesHelper
```

If you want to use your `CopiesHelper` in every controller of your app just do :

in **{app_dir}/app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include CopiesHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like helpers aren't generally used in controllers!